# Is there any good local gin or whiskey produced in South Korea?

Tags: whiskey, gin

When travelling I try to bring back home spirits from places I visit, mostly gin and whiskey.

I will be soon travelling to South Korea (Seoul and Busan), and I am trying to find out about the local gin and whiskey scene, but I can't find much - no producers or shops where I can buy them. I know that their neighbours (Japanese) are now famous with their gin and whiskey, but the situation in Korea seems to be quite different.

Does someone here have more insight and tips?

Further info:

- Sometimes I buy also other stuff like cognac, vodka, tequilla, and rum, depending on the place, so I can consider them too. I don't have anything against getting international/mainstream brands, but usually I can grab them in my town, and bringing local spirits as souvenirs contributes to a unique collection in a home bar.
- I know that Korea has several local beverages such as Cheongju, Soju, Hongju, and some herbal spirits, but I am not interested in those, as I use liquor mostly for cocktails so I am considering only the 'standard stuff'.

Comment: I'm yet to come across any Korean based whiskies. It appears like Soju and other rice-based liquors predominate there, but I couldn't tell you if native whisky or gin were a thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few that are popular in South Korea. One is the Imperial Scotch, [Scotch Blue](http://m.koreatimes.co.kr/pages/article.asp?newsIdx=5546) by Lotte Chilsun, and Windsor. They are sourced from Scottish distilleries for the Korean Market.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Golden Blue](http://www.goldenblue.co.kr/eng/index.php/index/main) in Busan.

While they do not distill their own whiskey, they do blend.

I read that they  plan to start distilling their own but i can not find any info on when this will happen.